# how to get router to work in a different file

Tags: node.js, express, router

How do i properly export out the router module to be used with the showscreen = true statement?? this is simplifed version of what im trying to do.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
const path = require('path');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var showscreen = require('./listening.js');
var router = express.Router();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server'));
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("hello");
    res.sendFile('C:/Users/O77616/Documents/practiceCode/client.html');
});

router.get('/server', function(req, res){
console.log("hello");
res.sendFile('C:/Users/O77616/Documents/practiceCode/grumpy.html');
});

app.post('/', function(req,res) {
   res.send('post it all');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
module.exports = function(app) {
   app.use('/server', router); 
};
```

listening.js

```
var server = require('./server.js');
var showscreen = true;
if (showscreen) {
   app.use('/server', server);

  //possibly insert more to make router.get work
}
```

so i want to export the router.get method to be used in the listening.js method depending on whether showscreen is true. currently app is not defined
i followed this tutorial but im still confused
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

UPDATE FROM COMMENTS:

server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();

var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.use('/', routes);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   console.log("hello");
   res.sendFile('C:/Users/O77616/Documents/practiceCode/client.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

routes/index.js

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 var showscreen = true;

if (showscreen) {
    router.get('/', function(request, response){ 
    response.sendFile('C:/Users/O77616/Documents/practiceCode/grumpy.html');
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

i deleted the listening.js file. not sure if this is clear but i want it so if showscreen is true grumpy.html will appear, else client.html, and the way my more complicated code works(this is very simplified) showscreen can only be accessed in index.js

Comment: You have 2 approach, to share `app` between the files, 1) export the route and use in server.js where you have access to `app`, 2) from listening.js, export a function which will accept `app` as an argument, and call that fn from server.js, passing it `app` as argument.

Comment: Right I'm just confused on how do that because I think I tried those methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server.js add following code

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();

app.use('/', routes);
```

// other code code related to initialize and start server

In your routes folder make a index.js . Having following code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET index page. */
router.get('/', function(request, response){
   //code to execute 
});

module.exports = router;
```

Hope you get it.

Comment: i tried to do this but my screen was taking an incredibly long time to load

Comment: no there isn't, let me update the the question and show you what my code looks like

Comment: Please check the example here on https://github.com/rupalipemare/Mongoose-Demo, wherein there is complete example.

Comment: actually i got it to work i had to put the var http after the app, thanks!!